# How to exclude some (nested) properties from models used in @SWG\Response

Tags: php, annotations, swagger-2.0, swagger-php

I write API in Php Laravel and use swagger (2.0) annotations (lib: [darkaonline/l5-swagger](https://github.com/DarkaOnLine/L5-Swagger) which use [swagger-php](https://github.com/zircote/swagger-php))  to generate swagger.json. I have following swagger:

```
@SWG\Definition(
    definition="Space",
    @SWG\Property( property="id", type="integer", example=33),
    @SWG\Property( property="name", type="string" ),
    @SWG\Property( property="dataA", type="string", example="very long data string" ),
    @SWG\Property( property="dataB", type="string", example="very long data string" ),
),

@SWG\Get(
    path="/api/v1/client/space/list",
    @SWG\Response( response=200, description="OK", 
        @SWG\Schema(
               type="array", 
               @SWG\Items(ref="#/definitions/Space"), 
        )
    )
)
```

Above api should return **list of Spaces** (to show in table) but I only need to get **id** and **name** - however **Space** also have very heavy fields **dataA** and **dataB** - which are non needed in table. Is there a way to exclude these fields without creating separate **Space** definition for response (to avoid breaking *"don't repeat yourself"* rule)? Is there some mechanism to do something like this:

```
@SWG\Items(ref="#/definitions/Space", exclude={"dataA","dataB"}),
```

And/or exclude more nested fields like

```
exclude={"dataA.securityField","dataA.someList[].heavyField"}
```

?

PS: I also report this as question/issue [here](https://github.com/zircote/swagger-php/issues/468).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there no exists implementation for such functionality as exclude (look [here](https://github.com/zircote/swagger-php/issues/468#issuecomment-348463309)). However you can try following partially acceptable approach (you create new definition but this definition reuse parts of **Space** definition):

```
@SWG\Definition(
    definition="SpaceListEntry",
    @SWG\Property( property="id", ref="#/definitions/Space/properties/id" ),
    @SWG\Property( property="name", ref="#/definitions/Space/properties/name" ),
)
```

And in `@SWG\Get` change `@SWG\Items(ref="#/definitions/Space"),` to

```
@SWG\Items(ref="#/definitions/SpaceListEntry"),
```

This solution is partially satisfying but better than full copy of **Space** definition.